# How to make multiple pages using one layout page ? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, datatable

How would I create a page with a list, and each item in the list is turned into a link at which will send you to another page where there are a list of question based only off the link. Hard to explain.

```
a table column called "quiz_name" in a database consist of 

id quiz_name     question_descripition
1  Jordan          How are you?
2  Jordan          How old are you?
3  Josh            Where are you from?
4  Jordan          Favorite Color?
5  Josh            Favorite Movie?
```

I created a page named quiz_name.php which I use

```
$mysql = "SELECT DISTINCT quiz_name FROM $table";
$mydata = mysql_query($mysql,$con);
while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
    $quizname=$records['quiz_name'];

    $_SESSION['quiz_name']=$quizname."</br>";
     echo $quizname;
    echo "<a href=http://localhost/xampp/Website_DataBase/Pvamu_website/quiz_folder/quiz_layout.php>".$quizname."</a></br>";
```

That displays a list of hyperlinks.

```
List:
 1. Jordan
 2. Josh
```

I want to click on Jordan and go to my quiz layout page and display all question based on quiz_name=Jordan

Then I want to click on Josh and go to my quiz layout page and display all question based on quiz_name=Josh

quiz_layout.php

```
Display(quiz_name)

Question #1
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3

Question #2
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
```

example:

```
Display(Jordan)

        How are you? #1
        Option 1
        Option 2
        Option 3

        How old are you #2
        Option 1
        Option 2
        Option 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since users can fiddle with GET variables in the browser address bar and you'll be using those variables in your SQL query, it would be better in quiz_name.php to use a form with the POST method and radio buttons for Jordan and Josh instead of links with the variables appended to the URL.

The PHP code in page_layout.php to capture the POST variable should be:

`$name = '';
if ( !empty( $_POST['name'] ) && $_POST['name'] != '' ) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}`

Then to get the right content for your quiz layout page you can use a WHERE clause in your SQL query. Something like (this is a PHP string):

```
"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $table.quiz_name = '$name'"
```

This will retrieve only the appropriate questions (from the question_description column) for the name (from the quiz_name column).

Comment: I'm a new to php and mysql and I found this method quicker and easier to code and to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Start of with a link like this:

```
<a href=?name=<?=$quizname?></a>
```

This will make sure you stay on the same page as you are now already.

The next part is to add some functionality to see if a name is actually set.

```
if($_GET['name'])
{
  //make sure to check user input! Never trust user input. Do that here. Please read some information about SQL injections and escaping input. Also use something like PDO.
  $quiz = $_GET['name']
  // Do a select where the name is equal on the input, and output the right questions.
}
```